# How to cycle through permutations of a list of 88 elements?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, permutation

I'm trying to assign a single variable each permutation of a list of 88 elements one after another. This means the variable would be re-assigned a new permutation 88! times. I have tried making 88 nested for-loops but apparently there is a limit to how many for-loops you can nest. I am using Python.

```
elements = [[211,76], [235,84], [240,88], [300,79], [230,100], [203,110], [202,95], [203,98], [214,97], [248,137], [249,111], [282,120], [263,144], [245,167], [192,172], [124,161], [322,146], [338,142], [355,146], [322,90], [343,105], [363,105], [368,116], [349,83], [348,67], [348,56], [390,75], [327,69], [443,73], [363,96], [396,104], [467,87], [499,87], [197,201], [199,200], [229,201], [227,219], [243,235], [403,166], [370,189], [399,212], [408,227], [214,292], [297,236], [352,276], [430,304], [437,348], [457,347], [430,277], [459,317], [709,153], [772,113], [828,103], [758,308], [767,320], [771,325], [803,330], [778,346], [795,348], [808,341], [834,341], [831,359], [762,391], [764,402], [817,404], [844,426], [827,440], [862,467], [729,433], [732,449], [747,477], [767,480], [657,454], [647,468], [649,467], [626,480], [670,499], [645,524], [652,547], [649,562], [688,566], [580,645], [580,645], [387,632], [419,625], [417,617], [419,614], [575,419]]
for x1 in elements:
    tempelements1 = elements.copy()
    tempelements1.remove(x1)
    for x2 in tempelements1:
        tempelements2 = tempelements1.copy()
        tempelements2.remove(x2)
        for x3 in tempelements2:
            tempelements3 = tempelements2.copy()
            tempelements3.remove(x3)
            for x4 in tempelements3:
                tempelements4 = tempelements3.copy()
                tempelements4.remove(x4)
                for x5 in tempelements4:
                    tempelements5 = tempelements4.copy()
                    tempelements5.remove(x5)
                    #...
                        for x88 in tempelements87:
                            for y1 in [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24, x25, x26, x27, x28, x29, x30, x31, x32, x33, x34, x35, x36, x37, x38, x39, x40, x41, x42, x43, x44, x45, x46, x47, x48, x49, x50, x51, x52, x53, x54, x55, x56, x57, x58, x59, x60, x61, x62, x63, x64, x65, x66, x67, x68, x69, x70, x71, x72, x73, x74, x75, x76, x77, x78, x79, x80, x81, x82, x83, x84, x85, x86, x87, x88]:
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you want me to post the code of 88 nested for-loops that cycle through P(88,88) permutations?

Comment: It might be useful to show *something*, if only so we can guess which language you're using.

Comment: 88 nested loops can't work.  But 99 nested loops might ;)  SERIOUSLY: 1) Please explain exactly what you're trying to do. It's not clear what your "goal" is, much less how you're attempting to solve it.  2) An [MCVE] would be helpful.  Even pseudo-code might help.  3) Q: What language are you using?

Comment: @jonrsharpe woops I am using Python. I will post an excerpted form of the 88 nested for-loops

Comment: @FoggyDay Hold on give me 2 minutes I'll reply to you

Comment: OK: Got it.  You're just trying to compute iterations on a list ... in the least efficient way possible ;)  An alternative might be to use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).  Look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-python/.  And KamikazeJones is correct: `n = 88!` is an intractably large list size ;)

Comment: @FoggyDay I am trying to find all groups of coordinates in this picture (https://imgur.com/a/DokmrLF) where the distance between every one of them in a group is less than 215.05813167606567. I have numerical coordinates for every point in the map.

Comment: PS: Python has no limit on the "#/nested loops" you can code in a program.  But for practical purposes, I would never nest any loop deeper than 3 or 4 (if that much!) before considering an alternative approach.  Write a new function, create a new class ... or consider using [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion).  For both "performance" and for "readability".

Comment: @FoggyDay So I thought about choosing one point, and then choosing a second point. If the second point is less than 215.05813167606567 separated from the first point, then it gets added to a list after the first point. Then a third point is chosen, and if it is less than 215.05813167606567 separated from all the other two points, then it is added, and so on.

Comment: @FoggyDay Did you read my new comment. I don't know how to do it

Comment: When you say "I am trying to find all groups of coordinates in this picture where the distance between every one of them in a group is less than 215.05813167606567" does that mean the real problem is a clustering problem where the sublist of elements are Lat/Long and you're trying to find partition into cluster with max distance of 215.05...?

Comment: @DarryIG Yes that is absolutely right

Comment: There has been previous discussions on clustering Lat/Long pairs such as [Clustering geo location coordinates (lat,long pairs)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/761/clustering-geo-location-coordinates-lat-long-pairs).  Article on cloustering [Geo Clustering 3,000,000 Points On The Fly: A Brief HOW TO](https://tech.willhaben.at/geo-clustering-3-000-000-points-on-the-fly-a-brief-how-to-9f04d8d5b3a7)

Comment: @DarryIG am making a new question with the other details I provided in the comments to be put in the question itself

Comment: Why not unwind each loop as well? The `for` construct is overrated

Answer (score 4):

This will not terminate in your lifetime. 88! = 1.854826e+134
This is like counting all atoms in the entire universe.
You have to try a different solving strategy for your problem.

Here is code to permute a list recursively, which avoids nesting the loops explicitly

```
def permuteIt(resultList,elementList):
    if len(elementList)==0:
        yield resultList
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(elementList)):
            resultList.append(elementList.pop(i))
            for l in permuteIt(resultList, elementList):
                yield resultList
            elementList.insert(i,resultList.pop())

for x in permuteIt([],[1,4,7,11]):
    print "result: ",x
```

Answer (score 2):

As another user said, you probably want a different algorithm: there are astronomically many permutations of 88 elements. That said, if you want permutations, look to the standard library's itertools module:

```py
from itertools import permutations

arr = [2,3,5]
for x in permutations(arr):
    print(x)
```

prints:

```
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 5, 3)
(3, 2, 5)
(3, 5, 2)
(5, 2, 3)
(5, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Yea but to iterate through the permutations the code has to make a list of the permutations and there is not enough memory to hold a list of 88! permutations.

Comment: @nacewv The permutations are evaluated lazily, and are not all stored in memory simultaneously. Even something like `for x in itertools.permutations(range(1_000)): print(x)` doesn't explode in memory usage. This is because the function returns an iterator, not a list.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to even iterate through 88! permutations ?? If so, then this would work for me

Comment: No. 88! nanoseconds is still more than 10^100 times the age of the universe.